# How can i delete file from /mnt/sdcard/ through Native Code

Tags: android

How can i delete file from /mnt/sdcard/ through Native Code ?
permission of sdcard in android "d---rwxr-x system   sdcard_rw          2013-01-29 14:39 sdcard"

permission of file in android " ----rwxr-x "

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the file by using the `delete()` method in `File`

```
File file = new File(pathToFile);
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

pathToFile is the path of the file in SDCARD.

Comment: thnxs for the reply , above solution is given if u want to delete file from android ,but i want to delete the file from Native C code.

Answer (score 0):

you mean delete file using adb command

> adb shell rm /sdcard/yourpath/file

from android application you can use

```
 String deleteCmd = "rm " + "/sdcard/yourpath/file";
                Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                try {
                    runtime.exec(deleteCmd);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    if (log != null)
                        log.error("IO Exception deleteFiles" + e);
                }
```

use execl to run above command using c

Comment: Let me explain ..Suppose you have created a file using android and saved it in sdcard , now i had read the data from that file using c code "fopen()" , now i want to delete the file from the C code using api "remove("") "...... but i am not abot delete the file , Getting error "Permission denied" ....

Comment: @ankitprajapati : make sure u have added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> Permission

Comment: have given  the permission. same as you quoted.